# ESXi standalone host cannot power on any virtual machines

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a standalone VMWare ESXi host on ESXi 5.1. It currently has a handful of VMs powered on, and they are running fine.

If I try to power on any other VM - any VM at all - I am receiving the following message:

[image]

> Power On virtual machine:A general system error occurred: The virtual machine could not start

I have been through everything on [KB2001005](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2001005) and [KB1006232](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006232) and their steps are either not applicable, or don't change anything. Nothing is generated in the virtual machine's log file.

Where can I troubleshoot from here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few steps to check... but the first thing to try is a restart of the management agents. Gain SSH access to your standalone host and run: `/sbin/services.sh restart` at the prompt.

Comment: Bam. That did the trick. I did do a restart from the powershell console, but doing it via SSH has fixed this problem. Hooray!

Comment: It may also be related with VM Swap files location in case they are located on separate DS. And may be related on free space available in Datastores, including dedicated DS for VM Swap files. So change swap file location, check free space and availability for all DS and then run `/sbin/services.sh restart`.